# simple measure over an image

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, photogrammetry

I need to take a measure (Euclidean distance) over a selected points on an image. In order to make this simpler I broke down all the process in steps:

1. Taking/Loading a photo (with a known pattern in it)
2. Recognizing the pattern to calibrate measure
3. Selecting points "from" and "to" in order to measure the distance between them

For my first iteration I will:

- load a picture (half of number 1),
- select the pattern manually (a rough approximation of number 2), and
- select point to measure distances between them.

I'm just beginning with OpenCV; do I need it for my first iteration?

Comment: You don't strictly *need* to use OpenCV, but I imagine it will make your task much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For described steps only OpenCV too massive library. But if you plan some kind of evolution for your project (recognition, detection,complicated image processing tasks), I think OpenCV can speed up your development process.

Comment: This is the planning for the first iteration. The next iteration will recognize automatically the pattern and will suggest landmarks about where to measure